# Regular expression include and exclude special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm finding a regular expression which adheres below rules.

Allowed Characters

Alphabet : a-z / A-Z
Numbers : 0-9
Special Characters : ~ @ # $  ^ & * ( ) - _ + = [ ]  { } | \ , .  ? :
(spaces should be allowed)

Not Allowed

Special Characters : < > ' " / ; ` %

Comment: What about the rest of the characters? Are they allowed or not?

Comment: Have you tried to come up with one? What exactly is the question you have about it?

Comment: And you just wanted to let us know that you found it? Thanks. Maybe this helps you too: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: https://regex101.com/ , this online tool helps us to build and compile a regular expression we need easily. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For the allowed characters you can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]*$
```

to validate a complete string that should consist of only allowed characters. Note that `-` is at the end (because otherwise it'd be a range) and a few characters are escaped.

For the invalid characters you can use

```
[<>'"/;`%]
```

to check for them.

To combine both into a single regex you can use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]*$)(?!.*[<>'"/;`%])
```

but you'd need a regex engine that allows lookahead.

Comment: could you please clarify how should I use your regex to allow only these characters in my strings & convert the rest all charcters to space character?

Answer (score 13):

You haven't actually asked a question, but assuming you have one, this could be your answer...

Assuming all characters, except the "Special Characters" are allowed you can write

```
String regex = "^[^<>'\"/;`%]*$";
```

Comment: could you please clarify how should I use your regex to allow only these characters in my strings & convert the rest all charcters to single whitespace character?

Comment: @user01 `text = text.replaceAll("[<>'\"/;%]", " ");` or if you want to combine multiple special characters and spaces `text = text.replaceAll("[<>'\"/;% ]+", " ");`

Comment: thanks so much, but in my case the disallowed characters are all except the allowed  ones(the allowed ones are same as in question). Could you suggest how to do that specifying the allowed ones: a-z / A-Z
/  0-9  ~ @ # $ ^ & * ( ) - _ + = [ ] { } | \ , . ? :

Comment: In that case `text = text.replaceAll("[^-A-Za-z0-9~@#$^&*()+=\\[\\]{}|\\\\,.?:]", " ");` The `[^ ]` at the start means anything but these characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\s]*
```

This would do the matching, if you only want to allow that just wrap it in ^$ or any other delimiters that you see appropriate, if you do this no specific disallow logic is needed.