# Jenkins Console section: What Java regex will trigger on string ERROR but not on string %%ERRORLEVEL%%?

Tags: java, regex, jenkins

I am using the Jenkins console sections plugin [1] on a windows server. It is excellent in order to make a nice left navbar on my logs.

Positively, I would like any error message to cause a section header, eg;

```
Assert-PathExstsNotTooLong : ERROR, The path does not exist: E:\P...
...
Oops! Error, please do not do that.
```

Negatively, I would like to be able to avoid having spelled-out execution templates cause a new section header, eg the below.

```
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C " c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 "E:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\M.sln"
```

Using references here on SO [2] and on the tester you recommended [3], I came up with the following, but it is not working?

```
^(?=(.*([Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr] ).*))(?!(%%ERRORLEVEL%%))
```

Using Regex101's amazing tester, with JS flavor, I used the above as input and had these test strings and outputs. The second line of match info perhaps explains my issue but I do not understand it.

```
test-strings = 
help error you should see me
i am %%errorlevel%% again
i am not a section

match-info; 
1.  `help error you should see me`
2.  `error `
```

Any tips? 
thank you!

1.[] ;This plugin uses Java Regex, per its docs ; ; ; ; X.Collapsing Console Sections Plugin - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki ; ; https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Collapsing+Console+Sections+Plugin

2.[] ; An example regex on characters, not strings, to avoid; ; ; ; X.java - Regular expression include and exclude special characters - Stack Overflow ; ; [Regular expression include and exclude special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173460/regular-expression-include-and-exclude-special-characters)

3.[] ; ; ; ; ; X.Online regex tester and debugger: JavaScript, Python, PHP, and PCRE ; ; https://www.regex101.com/#javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I can't add comments yet, otherwise I'd ask directly, but your example of a spelled-out message template doesn't include the text `%%ERRORLEVEL%%`, but I assume that it's meant to be a string with `%%ERRORLEVEL%%` somewhere in the middle of it. Also, as the example isn't quite right, I can't tell exactly what you mean by "not working")

Your problem is that your regex matches `ERROR_` (with a space) anywhere in the text, except where the text **is exactly** `%%ERRORLEVEL%%`. I think that instead you could write:

```
^(?=(.*([Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr])))(?!.*(%%ERRORLEVEL%%)).*
```

- Do you really need to only match `ERROR_` (with a space) as opposed to `ERROR` (whether or not it has a space)? If the former, then you are already excluding `%%ERRORLEVEL%%`, and you could just use `.*(?i:ERROR ).*` as the full regex.
- The Collapsing Console Sections Plugin uses [Java regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so you can use `(?i:ERROR)` to match `ERROR` case-insensitively.
- You need a trailing `.*` before and after your negative-lookahead atom for `%%ERRORLEVEL%%`, otherwise it will only exclude an exact match
- The documentation for the plugin doesn't say whether the pattern has to match a line completely, or if it just matches text within the line. If it matches the line completely, the leading `^` is unnecessary, but won't be doing any harm.
- You've got capturing brackets around `ERROR` and `%%ERRORLEVEL%%`. If you're not doing anything with that text, then those brackets are unnecessary.

The following regex will match any line with any of `ERROR`, `Error`, `error` etc in it, except lines with any of `%%ERRORLEVEL%%`, `%%ErrorLevel%%`, `%%errorlevel%%` etc.

```
^(?=.*(?i:ERROR))(?!.*(?i:%%ERRORLEVEL%%)).*
```

Comment: ty @Jelaby! 1.I made a tweak and now I'm pretty happy with it: <pre>^(?=(.*([Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr])))(?!.*(%%ERRORLEVEL%%))(?!.*(may get compilation errors.))(?!.*(errorreport:prompt)).*</pre> ; 2.The reason I was using 'error ' instead of 'error' is that many times the word error is repeated alot on multiple lines and on non-error lines. Instead now I exclude the key non-errors.; 3.An online tester for Java http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ , since JS regex gives '(?' is 'invalid group structure'. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's quite likely that Java's is a different flavour of regular expression from Javascript's, and (?i:) is a Perl/Java-specific system.

Regarding a tester: I've been testing with an actual Java development environment, so I can't really help you. A brief look at a Google search for "java regex tester" supplies a number of promising looking links.

If the cases where "error" is followed by a non-word character, like space, colon etc, then you could use `\b` like `(?i:ERROR\b)`. `\b` is matches a word-boundary - i.e. the change between a letter and a non-letter, or vice-versa.