# Regex with predefined start and end pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-messages

My regex pattern must start with /* and must end with */; between this it might contain all alphabets, numbers, special characters - zero or more times.

I have made the following regex expression for this:

```
 [/*][a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\s]*[*/;]
```

But this expression does not show error for patterns such as:

1. /*
2. / * sdfsdff
3. /* sdfsfeff *
4. /* fefef3323 */

Which is wrong. It must start with /* and end with */; at any cost.

Following is angular code for testing this pattern. Pls someone help out!

CODE:

```
<html>

<head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form name="form1" novalidate>
    {{form1.age.$error}}
    <input type="text" name="age" ng-model="myAge" ng-pattern="/^[/*][a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\s]*[*/;]$/" />
    <div ng-messages="form1.age.$error" >
        <span ng-message="pattern">This field has wrong pattern.</span>
    </div>
</form> 

<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ngMessages']);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    //code goes here ... 
});
</script> 

</body>

</html>
```

**Reference:**

[Regular expression include and exclude special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173460/regular-expression-include-and-exclude-special-characters)

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: remove character class from start and end

Comment: `[/][*][a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\s]*[*][/][;]`

Comment: try http://regexr.com/ for writing your regex

Comment: @rock321987 this is nice but will break on multi-lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets means *any of the contained* char. So change your regex to:

```
\/\*[a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\s]*\*\/;
```

You may read about [Regex charclass](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

---

*Side note:*

- you don't need to escape `.`, `?`, `()`, `*` and `{}` within classes
- `a-zA-Z0-9_` is equivalent to \w.
- within a char class, `-` means a range, thus `\)-_` means from ) to _

I would write:

```
\/\*[-\w~@#^$&*()+=\[\]{}|\\,.?\s]*\*\/;
```

Or, if you want to capture *anything* (even multi-lines comments):

```
\/\*[\w\W]*?\*\/;
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO5nH6/1)